# C++ vector object access

Tags: c++, object, vector

I am having trouble to access object in c++ vector. The vector is declared to hold custom class.

Class is defined as following:

```
class SPMgmt {
private:
    vector<Part> partList;
    vector<Supplier> supplierList;
public:
    SPMgmt();
    SPMgmt(fstream&, fstream&);

    void listPart();
    void listSupplier();
    void searchPartBySupplierName(string);
    void searchSupplierByPartCode(string);
    void addNewPart();
};
```

Here is the class Supplier:

```
class Supplier{
public:
    // Constructor of an empty Supplier class object
    Supplier (){}

    // Constructor of a non-empty Supplier object
    Supplier (const string& new_name, const string& new_code,
             const string& new_phone, const string& new_strt_addr,
             const string& new_city_state_zip){
        name = new_name;
        code = new_code;
        phone_number = new_phone;
        street_address = new_strt_addr;
        city_state_zip = new_city_state_zip;
    }

    // Copy constructor
    Supplier (const Supplier& other){}

    // Assignment operator
    Supplier& operator= (const Supplier& rightSide){return *this;}

    // Destructor -releases any memory allocated to a Supplier object
    ~Supplier (void){}

    // Used to display a Supplier object to standard output
    void display (ostream& output) const;   // const was added

    // Accessor functions:
    string get_name ( ) const{return this->name;}
    string get_code ( ) const{return this->code;}
    string get_phone ( ) const{return this->phone_number;}
    string get_street_address ( ) const{return this->street_address;}
    string get_city_state_zip ( ) const{return this->city_state_zip;}

    // Mutator functions:
    void set_name (const string& new_name){this->name = new_name;}
    void set_code (const string& new_code){this->code = new_code;}
    void set_phone (const string& new_phone){this->phone_number = new_phone;}
    void set_street_address (const string& new_street_addr){this->street_address = new_street_addr;}
    void set_city_state_zip(const string& new__city_st_zip){this->city_state_zip = new__city_st_zip;}

private:
    string name;
    string code;           // Addd where A is an upper case letter and
                          // the d's are digits
    string phone_number;
    string street_address;
    string city_state_zip;
};
```

And its constructor is not working right:

```
SPMgmt::SPMgmt(fstream& supplierFile, fstream& partFile){
    string name, code, phone, streetAddr, cityStateZip;

    while(std::getline(supplierFile, name)){
        std::getline(supplierFile, code);
        std::getline(supplierFile, phone);
        std::getline(supplierFile, streetAddr);
        std::getline(supplierFile, cityStateZip);

        Supplier newSupplier(name, code, phone, streetAddr, cityStateZip);

        // get_name() prints out supplier name
        cout<<"Name: "<<newSupplier.get_name()<<endl;

        // try to put object newSupplier to the vector
        supplierList.push_back(newSupplier);

        // PROBLEM: get_name() here did not print name. It prints empty string. 
        cout<<"Name: "<<supplierList[0].get_name()<<endl;
    }
```

My question is: why the object stored in vector did not print its name properly? I can just use the get_name() function to print its name before push_back() it to the vector.

Comment: Let me make sure I understand your quesiton. You're asking why a class, whose definition you did not show, is not working correctly? How do you expect anyone to tell you what's wrong with a class, `Supplier`, whose definition is not provided?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to post class Supplier...

Comment: `Supplier (const Supplier& other){}`: what do you think happens when your object gets copied into the vector? Your assignment operator is also incorrect. Delete both.

Comment: your copy constructor does nothing, thus you have empty supplier

Comment: you misunderstood rule of three, because now you have strings which implement rule of three so you don't need to care

Comment: Thank you all ... After deleting operator= override and copy constructor, it now can print out the name. Never dig into these two functions to find problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither your copy-constructor nor your assignment operator in the `Supplier` class does anything useful.

The copy-constructor and assignment operator that the compiler generates automatically should work fine for your class, so you should remove the copy-constructor and assignment operator, and follow [the rule of zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three#Rule_of_zero).

Comment: Thanks for your answer and link!